How to get the difference between two columns between two SQL tables using SQL queries?
Table 1:
Name    Address   Height    Weight
X.        y         z.        p
G.        H.        I         J
Q         W.        E.        R

Table 2:
Name    Income     Tax    
X.        y         z.      

Table 1 has more rows than table 2. All the Names in table 2 are in table 1 but not all the names of table 1 are in table 2.
Is there anyway to compare the rows between the two tables and get the names that appear only in table 1 and not in table 2 as well? mySQL

You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem, nor specify which type of SQL/DBMS you are actually using.

yes there is a way.  Look up the MINUS operator for example

A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result.

Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

I am using MySQL

Could you please explain more detailed what exactly you want to do? Your sample data is really vague. Are the names unique? Do you care about other columns? Let's say, you have another row in table2 with name G., but income and tax have other values. What to do then? It is just random that the other two columns of the x rows have the same values (address and income both y, hieght and tax both z.) or does this matter?

Use common
SELECT name FROM table_1
EXCEPT
SELECT name FROM table_2

Set Operations with UNION, INTERSECT, and EXCEPT

quick question, is this case sensitive?

@winterlyrock Depends on name column's collation.

You can easily set others to null I believe if you are using mySQL.
SELECT t1.Name
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
WHERE t2.Name IS NULL;


No need to join because they don't want to select from table2.

Try this...
WITH  /* - S a m p l e    D a t a : */

  tbl_1 ( Name, Address, Height, Weight ) AS
    ( Select 'X.',      'y',         'z.',       'p'   Union All
      Select 'G.',      'H.',        'I',        'J'   Union All
      Select 'Q',       'W.',        'E.',       'R'
    ), 
  tbl_2 ( Name,  Income,  Tax  ) AS  
    ( Select 'X.',   'y',    'z.'  )

    /* S Q L : */

Select     t1.*
From       tbl_1 t1
Left Join  tbl_2 t2 ON(t2.Name = t1.Name)
Where      t2.Name Is Null;


Is this MySQL? I am using MySQL

@winterlyrock This SQL should work with any rdbms - it is a standard SQL.

WITH is implemented in version 8+.

@TheImpaler True, but With is here just to show sample data - OP works with the tables from database. He just needs to adjust the SQL with Left Join.

For MySql,
select * from table1 t1 
where t1.Name not in (
    select t2.Name from table2 t2  
)


NOT IN is risky due to possible NULL values, you can avoid this using NOT EXISTS

Avoid NOT IN unless you are 100% positive there are no nulls. Otherwise stay clear of it.

If you want to include only the names that exist in both tables along with their differences, you can use the INNER JOIN
SELECT 
    t1.Name,
    t1.Height,
    t2.Income,
    (t1.Height - t2.Income) AS Height_Income_Difference,
    t1.Weight,
    t2.Tax,
    (t1.Weight - t2.Tax) AS Weight_Tax_Difference
FROM 
    Table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
    Table2 t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name;

And If you also want to get the differences between columns for the rows that match between the two tables, along with the names that appear only in Table 1, you can use the following query
SELECT 
    t1.Name,
    t1.Height,
    t2.Income,
    (t1.Height - IFNULL(t2.Income, 0)) AS Height_Income_Difference,
    t1.Weight,
    t2.Tax,
    (t1.Weight - IFNULL(t2.Tax, 0)) AS Weight_Tax_Difference
FROM 
    Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN 
    Table2 t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name;


SELECT t1.Name
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
WHERE t2.Name IS NULL;

